# Wildcard in Classpath Archive specification for a launcher not working?

Tags: install4j

For a few of our launchers, we want to add an archive to the `Classpath`.

E.g.

```
foo\bar\foo-bar-1.0.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
```

However the version keeps changing.

As per documentation, wildcard is allowed for the last path component. Therefore, we have specified this has:

```
foo\bar\foo-bar-*.jar
```

This does not seem to work and we get `ClassNotFoundException` for classes in this `jar.` We are using install4j 6.1.4.

Any suggestion on what we might be doing wrong?

Comment: This should work. If on Windows, please check the log file that you get by launching with the parameter /create-i4j-log from the command line, it shows the actual class path. On Unix, check the start script. What did it add for this entry?

Comment: For the -Djava.class.path parameter, it shows it as:
-Djava.class.path=...;C:\Program Files\XXX\bin\..\XXX\foo-*.jar

So looks like it's not resolving the path as expected.

Comment: I cannot reproduce this here. I would suspect that the file does not exist at compile-time. Please send a small test case to support@ej-technologies.com.

Comment: I was able to reproduce it with a test case. When files and the launcher belong to a non-default fileset, the wildcard is not expanded. I will email you the test case at the above email address.